# Accessing additional properties from JSON received through store's load method

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a grid that loads data via a JSON store, however there are some additional properties beyond the records themselves that I need to access. Here's an example of what the JSON data looks like:

```
{
    success: true,
    records: [
        {id: 1, name: 'bob'},
        {id: 2, name: 'fred'}
    ],
    extraProperty: 'foo'
}
```

I need to access that extraProperty when the grid data is loaded. So I assume I'd want to a callback, like so:

```
store.load({
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        //somehow access extraProperty here
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what to do inside that callback. The operation variable, an Ext.data.operation.Operation object, has a private method called getResponse(). It returns an object in Chrome that has a responseJson property, but in IE it instead has a responseText property that needs to be decoded. So I could handle both scenarios, but since it's a private method I don't really want to rely on it in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `keepRawData` config on the reader.

```
store.load({
    callback: () => {
        const { extraProperty } = store.getProxy().getReader().rawData;
    }
});
```

Depending on your needs, you may also want to look at `preserveRawData` as well.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried on the store level, something like below

under proxy in the reader config section

```
proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  actionMethods: {
    read: 'GET'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  api: 'your url',
  reader: {
      extraProperty: 'extraProperty'
  }
}
```